# SharePoint 2010 without fixed section at top

Tags: 2010, master-page, css, branding

Which is the best approach for SharePoint 2010 without a fixed area at top?

Comment: Do you want fixed width design for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: No, I looking for a design without a fixed bar at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Expand the scrollbar past the ribbon than please follow steps mentioned in below given URL.

[Expanding the scrollbar past the ribbon.](https://myspexp.com/2010/06/14/expanding-the-scrollbar-past-the-ribbon-2/)

It will work for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that this option has a downside?

Comment: No not at all. As even I had tried the same for one of my site in SP 2010.

Comment: Is that works for you?

Comment: Did not tested yet ...

Comment: ohh ok... Please let me know if you need any help in it.

Comment: Works!! Something strange is that I had to add   body { overflow: scroll !important; }   on the master page to work. I have taken the idea of point 5 of your article. Opinion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40001/discussion-between-hardik-and-jpussacq).

Comment: It will work with the same resolution which you applied but it will show the scrollbar even if it's not needed in your page.

Comment: Any recommendation?

Comment: You need to put **auto** inplace of **scroll**.